# Removing an Array Object if key is found

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove a whole array object if a `$key=>value` matches?

For example in my data I have `["endDate"]=> string(10) "2017-06-24"` and if that date matches todays `date('Y-m-d')` I would like the whole object bock to be removed from the `$row`

**Code:**

```
foreach ($json->data as $row)
{       
   $date = date('Y-m-d');

   if($row->endDate == $date){

    $search = array_search($date, array_column('endDate', $row));

    unset($row[$search]);

    if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate))== date('Y-m-d'))
    {
        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName'      => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName'       => $row->guestLastName,
            'email'          => $row->guestEmail,
            'country'        => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date'  => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
        $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
$response = $o->curl(sprintf($url, $propertyID, $pageSize, $pageNumber, $resultsFrom));
$json = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Where does the $json object populate the data from? unset($row[$search]) won't work because basically $row is just a copy of the data. You would need an unset method from the class that the $json object is created from.

Comment: @AuntJamaima I have updated my question to include the JSON creation point :)

Comment: You want to remove all rows where the date matches today from the json object, correct?

Comment: @AuntJamaima Yes :) where the $row->endDate = Today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($json->data as $index=> $row){
    if($row->endDate == $date) unset($json->data{$index});
}

foreach ($json->data as $row){
    if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate))== date('Y-m-d'))
     {
        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName'      => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName'       => $row->guestLastName,
            'email'          => $row->guestEmail,
            'country'        => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date'  => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
        $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    }
  }
```

You may also consider just skipping to the next iteration, since it looks like you are building a guest email list and are not trying to modify the source of the json feed.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
foreach ($json->data as $row){
    if($row->endDate == $date) {
       continue;
    }

     if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate))== date('Y-m-d'))
     {
        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName'      => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName'       => $row->guestLastName,
            'email'          => $row->guestEmail,
            'country'        => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date'  => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
        $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    }
}
```

Between the two options I pose, the second one requires less code and will yield slightly faster execution times.

Comment: this is also help fulll for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you place an ampersand before $row in your foreach you can change $json->data directly. From what you wrote, I think I understand your question and this may be what you need.

```
foreach ($json->data as &$row)
    {       
       $date = date('Y-m-d');

       if ($row->endDate == $date) {

        $search = array_search($date, array_column('endDate', get_object_vars($row)));

        unset($row[$search]);

        if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails) && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->startDate))== date('Y-m-d'))
        {
            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName'      => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName'       => $row->guestLastName,
                'email'          => $row->guestEmail,
                'country'        => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date'  => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
            $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
        }
      }
    }
```

If not then rephrase your question so I might provide the answer you need.

Comment: Thanks however this gives me an error of 
Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in 
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Comment: In that line of your code you need to convert your object to an array. I have corrected that line above for you.

Comment: It appears that in that line you are searching _all_ end dates in `$json->data`, correct?